# Continuous vector field on surface

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

On plane we can easy to define continuous vector field:
$$\mathbb{R}^2\ni x\longmapsto v(x)\in\mathbb{R}^2,$$
where real-valued function $v_1(x)$ and $v_2(x)$ are continuous.

But when we try to define field on arbitrary 2-dimensional surface we have a trouble:
$$v(x_1)\in T_{x_1}S,~~~v(x_2)\in T_{x_2}S,$$
and for different points $x_1$ and $x_2$ tangent spaces $T_{x_1}S$ and $T_{x_2}S$ are different. So function $v_1$ and $v_2$ no sense.

Question: how to define **continuous** vector field on **surface**?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#Vector_fields

Comment: @Qiaochu: Is it necessarily to consider tangent bundle?

Comment: Nope. One can also define vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$ as derivations on $C^{\infty}(M)$: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(abstract_algebra)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(abstract_algebra))

Comment: Perhaps we should also mention the notion of a connection (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_%28differential_geometry%29 ) which is essentially a way to identify tangent spaces at different points on the base manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, it'd be nice if all tangent vectors to $M$ were elements of some big space; then we could talk about the function assigning a point to the vector at that point being "continuous", 
or "smooth", etc. If we were working in a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, perhaps we could try to compare the tangent vectors within $\mathbb{R}^n$; but when we're working in an abstract manifold, we have to do everything ourselves.

The answer is simply to "put all of the $T_pM$'s together", and voila, we have a big space that contains all of our tangent vectors!

The resulting object is known as the [tangent bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle), and as far as I know, this is the main reason why it was invented. As a set, it's precisely
$$TM=\coprod_{p\in M}T_pM$$
and it also gets a topology (though clearly it's not going to be the [disjoint union topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_%28topology%29)), and it also has a natural smooth manifold structure. It comes with  a natural projection map $\pi:TM\to M$ defined by taking the elements of $T_pM$ to $p$.

A continuous [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds) is then just a continuous section of $\pi$.

Comment: May I roughly say for 2-dimensional surface $S$, that vector field on $S$ is continuous if under action of (local) homeomorphism $\Psi : S\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ field maps to continuous field no plane?

Comment: That's a correct statement; since continuity is a local condition and the charts are homeomorphisms, the vector field is continuous iff its composition with each chart is continuous.

Comment: ...and define tangent vectors as $\dot\gamma(t_0)$ (where $\gamma(t):\mathbb{R}\to S$ and $\gamma(t_0)=x$)

Comment: Well, that's the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t_0)=x$, but two different curves could have the same tangent vector at a point, so you really have to consider equivalence classes of curves (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves)).